# Using the same component in ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs, components

​I have several extjs grid I define them as below :

```
var aGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({

    bbar : pagingToolbar
});

var bGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({

    bbar : pagingToolbar
});
```

But if I use the `pagingToolbar` as above it doesn't work as expected.
Only the first grid works, in the 2nd grade the toolbar does not appear.
Only one grid is active at a time. We do

```
myTabPanel.hideTabStripItem(aGrid); 
myTabPanel.add(bGrid).show();
aGrid.bbar = null;
bGrid.bbar = pagingToolbar;
```

Comment: You can't put the same apple in two different spots on your table at the same time. Same goes for components... Why do you want to do that? If you want two components with the same properties/behaviours, create a class and instantiate it twice.

Comment: @rixo ​I'm not using the `pagingtoolbar` control at the same time. I have updated the question. Would it still be a problem in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should instantiate them as follow:

```
var aGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({

    bbar : pagingToolbar1
});

var bGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({

    bbar : pagingToolbar2
});
```

Another way that I've been using is:

```
var aGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({

    bbar : { xtype: 'pagingtoolbar', store: 'Ext.data.Store'}
});

var bGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({

    bbar :{ xtype: 'pagingtoolbar', store: 'Ext.data.Store'}
});
```

Using two instance of each object (such as store or pagingtoolbar) is absolutely necessary.

Comment: ​I'm not using the `pagingtoolbar` control at the same time. I have updated the question. Would it still be a problem in this case?

Comment: No, it wouldn't be a problem if you change the config of grid before rendering it, but after showing one component changing it's config wouldn't update its appearance.

Comment: One important thing is to use different instance of a component, because each component holds the DOM elements of that component which has been rendered.